# react-router-dom translation functionality not being passed to components correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

1. I have a React application that I'm upgrading to React Router v6 and am having some
   difficulty in getting the translation functionality to execute correctly.
2. The App.js and EntryPoint.js components were previously class components that have been
   converted to function components as this seems to be the preferred path according to the
   react router upgrade documentation ( version 5.3 -> version 6)

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PageNotFound from "./components/PageNotFound";
import EntryPoint from "./components/entrypoint";

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading...">
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
          <Route path="/:dealership/*" element={<EntryPoint />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export { App };
export default connect(null, null)(App);
```

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const EntryPoint = (props) => {
  const { userPermissions } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Session />
      <TopOfPage />
      <MainContent />
      <BottomOfPage />
    </div>
  );
}
export {EntryPoint};
export default connect(null,null)(EntryPoint);
```

3. App.js evaluates the initial request before routing to applications entry point for
   further evaluation. If no match is found, the PageNotFound is displayed:

   a. PageNotFound still makes use of the HOC "withTranslation" and does render the
   translation correctly

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "react";
import {withTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

const PageNotFound = (props){
    const {t} = props;

    return(
        <div>
            {t('PageNotFoundMessage')}
        </div>
    );
}

PateNotFound.PropTypes ={
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired;  
};

export {PageNotFound};
export default withTranslation('mainApp/PageNotFound')(PageNotFound);
```

4. If the user is routed to EntryPoint, the MainContent element will be created and this contains additional routes to be evaluated

   a. At this point, the translation ability seems to have been dropped or otherwise not
   correctly passed through. The props are on the EntryPoint element, but nothing that
   pertains to translation functionality is included.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import {appStore} from '../appStore';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


const MainContent = (props) =>{

    const {userPerm} = props;
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const {languageData} = appStore.getState();

    return (
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="Chevy">
            <Route path="trucks" t={t} userPerm={userPerm} />
            <Route path="cars" t={t} userPerm={userPerm} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="Ford">
            <Route path="trucks" t={t} userPerm={userPerm} />
            <Route path="cars" t={t} userPerm={userPerm} />
          </Route>
          
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
}
export default MainContent;
```

5. The MainContent loads and evaluates the routes. Again, the translation functionality does
   not seem to have been passed down through the props.

   a. I have attempted to specifically make reference in the MainContent element by
   importing useTranslation, but when this reference gets passed along from MainContent
   to the child elements that make use of the 't' function, although the 't' function
   executes in the elements it is passed to, it only returns "missing key" error which
   makes me believe that I have structured this incorrectly because the files must be
   present or else the PageNotFound component would not be able to perform correct
   translations and the Suspense element is used.
6. Is there some glaring error I am making that prevents these translations from rendering
   correctly in the nested elements?

Comment: would be nice to have a reproducible example.... maybe there is some hint in the developer console, if you set the debug flag of i18next to true?

Comment: you may also want to post your i18next config